# How to submit an option and text input form with AngularJS

Tags: java, html, angularjs, forms

I'm new to setting up forms and I need to be able to submit two separate values to a Java backend on a different server. One of the values is a predefined one which should come from a `select` and the other from a text `input` field.

On the front end the user will select an option from the dropdown and input text in the textbox and then hit the submit button to send it off to the backend.

I am having trouble with the setup of this and was looking for some pointers. I have some code which paints an idea of what I've been trying to do.

```
    <div class="col-xs-3">

<label>Search Criteria:</label>
<select class="form-control" tabindex="20">
  <option value="0" disabled selected>Select your criteria</option>
  <option value="1">Project Reference</option>
  <option value="2">Service Owner</option>
  <option value="3">Service Name</option>
  <option value="4">Service Abbreviation</option>
  <option value="5">Domain Abbreviation</option>
  <option value="6">Domain Name</option>
</select>
 </div>

  <div class="col-xs-3">
  <label>Search Terms:</label>
    <form name="options" class="form-inline">
  <div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" tabindex="21" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for..." ng-model="mytext" required>
  <button type="submit" tabindex="22" style="color: #ffffff; 
  background-color: #007381;" class="btn btn-default" ng-disabled="options.$invalid"><b>Go </b><b></b><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></button>
   </div>
</form>
  </div>
```

Comment: It will help you. You can make as many ajax requests as you want. All you need to use angular's `$http` service. Read this https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to make multiple $http service calls. You could do it inside a controller like this:

```
.controller('YourController', function($http) {
  var controller = this;
  this.saveCriteria = function(criteria) {
    $http({method: 'POST', url: '/backend_url_handle_criteria', data: criteria})
    .success(function(data) {
        //do something with data
    }
  };
  this.saveTerm = function(term) {
    $http({method: 'POST', url: '/backend_url_handle_term', data: term})
    .success(function(data) {
        //do something with data
    }
  };
      this.send = function(formdata){
          this.saveCriteria(formdata.criteria);
          this.saveTerm(formdata.term);
      };
});
```

In your html you declare your form something like this

```
<form name="yourForm" ng-controller="YourController as yourCtrl" ng-submit="yourCtrl.send(formdata)">
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. So essentially have form tags like the below surround the select and input and they would then need an `id` of `saveTerm` and `saveCriteria` to match them up.

The url will be where I want the data to be sent to, correct?

Comment: I forgot to add that this then gets back a JSON response from the Java backend. This should happen as well once the request is submitted. Would the `GET` possibly fit in there too?

Comment: 1 - Yes something like that. You could have a javascript object with term and criteria as properties. The url in the $http service is your backend service url.
2 -  You can use GET if you want to.
I suggest you read about the $http service, promises (.success, .then ...) and the ng-model directive for your form